# dynamically change UIImageView x-position in auto layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout, constraints

I have a custom table view cell with `UILabel` and `UIImageView` that designed with constraints. I want to set the `UIImageView` x-postion as after label end. So `UIImageView` x-postion will change periodically.

How I handle this situation? even I set the frame in coding which doesn't change while Autolayout.

Comment: you need to give horizontal spacing between label and imageview. and give label width constraint to (>=)

Comment: I set the label trailing space constraint to (>=). Now its working fine. Thank you!